# Objective c autorelease question

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

Hey, I've got a quick autorelease question. I understand basically how it works, but I was wondering if the following would create a memory leak.

```
NSAutoreleasePool* pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

NSString* string = [[[NSString alloc] init] autorelease];
[[string retain] autorelease];

[pool drain];
```

Will the string be sent two release messages?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Think of the your interaction with the retain count of an object purely as a delta.

If you increase it by one, you need to decrease it by one for that object to potentially be released.

So -- yes -- you increased it by one twice and decreased it by one twice in that code.  Two releases on drain will be the result.

Answer (score 2):

That will not create a memory leak and you are correct, it will be sent two release messages from the auto release pool. As long as you have one release/autorelease for every alloc/retain/copy you should not be getting any leaks.